# How can I play a track from a specific minute and second using Web Playback SDK?

Tags: javascript, spotify

Anybody knows how can I play a track from a specific minute and second using Web Playback SDK?

> **Example**: spotify:track:20zCnBjK6aIgvvy66qZ7RV from 00:44.

Is there anyway to add this info to the Spotify URI?
This is the code,

```
play({
  spotify_uri: 'spotify:track:20zCnBjK6aIgvvy66qZ7RV',
  playerInstance: player,          
});
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add `#0:44` at the end of your uri. Info obtained from https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Playlist-with-quot-start-at-specific-time-quot-function/td-p/1547529

```
play({
  spotify_uri: 'spotify:track:20zCnBjK6aIgvvy66qZ7RV#0:44',
  playerInstance: player,          
});
```

If this doesn't work try:

```
play({
      spotify_uri: 'spotify:track:20zCnBjK6aIgvvy66qZ7RV',
      playerInstance: player,
      position_ms: 44000
    });
```

Based on https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/start-a-users-playback/

Comment: `{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Invalid track uri in payload"
  }
}`

Comment: try adding this property: `position_ms: 44000` based on the documentation here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/start-a-users-playback/ I am not 100% sure if thats the problem.

Comment: Make sure your play function send `position_ms` as a body parameter.